# How to fix issue with local storage?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have a popup, which appears in 5(now) seconds after screen loading.
It has a special button - 'don't show more'. If user clicks on it, the popup has to not appear more.

html part(without other content)

```
 <div class="popup-footer">
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-inner d-flex">        
        <div class="popup-image">           
        </div>  
        <div class="popup-form">
            <div class="nevermore" id="nevermore">  Don't show again</div>          
        </div>
        <span class="fa-close popup-close"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery part

```
jQuery(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     jQuery('.popup-footer').show();
     jQuery('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');     
   },5000);
}); 
    
jQuery('.popup-close').on("click", function(){
 jQuery(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('.popup-footer').hide();
jQuery('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');  
  });   
    
    
jQuery('div#nevermore').on("click", function(){
 jQuery(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').parent('.popup-footer').hide();
jQuery('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');      
  });       

    
    
let popupState = localStorage.getItem('popup_open');

if (popupState) {
    jQuery('.popup-footer').show();
}

jQuery('div#nevermore').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.popup-footer').hide();
    localStorage.setItem('popup_open', 1);
});
```

It doesn't work - even if I change the if-part from show to hide. The popup appears even if I click the button.If I change show to hide it doesn't appear at all. I work with localStorage at first. What do I miss? The localStorage key is wrong? Please help me to understand.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem. But you can clean up your code by not using so many parent calls. Just call **closest** ONCE like **jQuery(this).closest('.popup-footer').hide();**

Comment: You can also combine the click handlers for nevermore. You don't need two

Comment: Also, if you want the popup_open localStorage item to not allow the popup to open, why are you using show? I would move your if statement around the setTimeout to say **if(!popupState** and move the popupstate declaration to the top of your code too

Comment: I tried closest, didn't work by some reason, I'll  back to it later, now I need to fix '#nevermore'

Comment: now closest works, thanks, I think I've made some syntax mistake and thought it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You've set the popup to *always* appear after 5 seconds, unconditionally:

```
jQuery(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('.popup-footer').show();
    jQuery('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');     
  },5000);
});
```

If this should only happen based on some condition, wrap it in that condition:

```
if (popupState) {
  jQuery(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery('.popup-footer').show();
      jQuery('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');     
    },5000);
  });
}
```

Though, is `if (popupstate)` really the condition you want?  Aren't you setting that value in `localStorage` if the user *doesn't* want to see the popup again?  In which case it would be:

```
if (!popupstate) {
```

(You'll also need to move the creation of `popupstate` to the top of the code in order to use it before its current declaration line.)

Comment: I tried both !popupstate and popupstate, without success. 
I found the example about  let popupState = localStorage.getItem('popup_open') in Internet, is it right at all? I'm new in it.   Code is now

Comment: '''
let popupState = localStorage.getItem('popup_open');

if (!popupState) {
    jQuery(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     jQuery('.popup-footer').show();
  jQuery('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');  
   },5000);
}); 
}

jQuery('div#nevermore').on('click', function() {
   jQuery(this).closest('.popup-footer').hide()
    localStorage.setItem('popup_open', 1);
});
 
jQuery('.popup-close,div#nevermore').on("click", function(){
jQuery(this).closest('.popup-footer').hide()
jQuery('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden'); 
  }); 
'''

Comment: @libertarian: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/6r4dfgew/).  As for trying both... Don't just try random things and hope for the best.  Understand what you're trying to achieve, and debug and observe the behaviors of the code.  Regarding the updated code... Code in comments like that is unreadable.  Perhaps you have a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Maybe something else is showing your popup?  (In the code shown in the question you show the popup *twice*.  First when the page loads, then again 5 seconds later.)

Comment: I'm really hard to understand localStorage, so I decided to test it in practice. In some other questions testing in practice helped to understand

Comment: @libertarian: *"I'm really hard to understand localStorage"* - Then you're **probably** overthinking it.  `localStorage` is a persisted storage of key/value pairs in the browser.  The keys and values are always strings.  You can write key/value pairs to it, and you can read those key/value pairs from it.  That's... the entirety of it.

Comment: so I have to create that key/value pair for popup_open? And that's why it doesn't works - cause I have to create it at first? 'popup_open' itself has to be a key or a value?

Comment: @libertarian: Again, you're overthinking it.  In your code in the question, `'popup_open'` is the key and `1` is the value.  Now would be a good time for you to create a [mcve] which demonstrates whatever problem you think you're observing.  Because, [as previously demonstrated](https://jsfiddle.net/6r4dfgew/), the suggestion made in this answer addresses the problem described in the question.  There may be *other* problems, which can be addressed in *other* questions, but "I don't understand local storage" is not an answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

Take the boolean value from your checkbox, then have a conditional statement to run the `setTimeout` after the value of your checkbox passes through the conditional.
Though this approach will not work across sessions.

Describe the desired behavior to yourself and if you need to use the word "if" when explaining it, the function will more than likely need to be part of a conditional statement.